# ExtJS viewModel type

Tags: extjs

I seen some code like this

`viewModel: {        type: 'uservm',            },`

In the docs I can read that

> viewModel : String/Object/Ext.app.ViewModel The ViewModel is a data
>   provider for this component and its children. The data contained in
>   the ViewModel is typically used by adding bind configs to the
>   components that want present or edit this data.
>
> When set, the ViewModel is created and links to any inherited
>   viewModel instance from an ancestor container as the "parent". The
>   ViewModel hierarchy, once established, only supports creation or
>   destruction of children. The parent of a ViewModel cannot be changed
>   on the fly.
>
> If this is a root-level ViewModel, the data model connection is made
>   to this component's associated Data Session. This is determined by
>   calling getInheritedSession.
>
> Defaults to: {$value: null, lazy: true}

Object links me to an object docs (obviously)

`Ext.app.ViewModel` doesn't have `type` property.

**Question is** : what is that `type` property, where can I read about it, what other properties are available for `viewModel` declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set an [`alias`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-alias) for your view models (using the `viewmodel` namespace).

> List of short aliases for class names. An alias consists of a namespace and a name concatenated by a period as .

Comment: so that's just like `alias` of a `Component` and `xtype` which uses that alias?

Comment: Yes, components use the widget namespace while view models use the viewmodel namespace.

Answer (score 5):

An example to clarify the usage of alias and type:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.myapp-main',

    data: {
        stuff: 42
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'myapp-main'
    }
    // viewModel now has data.stuff = 42
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but @cd was little earlier (hovewer I still upvoting yours, since example is good)

Comment: Thanks, the example was to clarify their answer.